# Php explode function may cause overload

Tags: php, overloading, explode

i've a big string in my code. My goal is to extract a portion (quite little) of this string depending on a start and end delimiter.

Actually i do in this way:

```
$string = "....";
$parts = explode($startDel, $string);
$parts = explode($endDel, $parts[1]);
$finalStr = $parts[0];
```

Since this part of code will be called more and more times, i don't known if use explode is the right way. So i'm open to all yours ideas.

Thanks a lot,
bye

Comment: how about the regular expression functions?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not really pratical with regexp, u have some example related on my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use third parameter to `explode`, to make sure it will create only two elements, without searching for delimiter in rest of string.

However it looks like perfect task for simple `strpos` and `substr`. Example function that implements this:

```
function str_extract($string, $start = '[', $end = ']', $offset = 0) {
    $pos_start = strpos($string, $start, $offset) + strlen($start);
    $pos_end = strpos($string, $end, $pos_start);
    return substr($string, $pos_start, $pos_end - $pos_start);
}
```